# @CsvRecord(separator="${file.seperator}", generateHeaderColumns = true)

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

file.seperator is not taking value from properties file, it is always taking last character "}" as seperator,

Can someone help me...?

Comment: Are you sure "seperator" is the correct word, not a type? "separator" is correct.

Comment: yeah, spelling is correct...

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported, you cannot do that. The separator attribute is used as the value as-is.

Comment: I really don't understand why expression language is not being evaluated,Could you explain me why is it not supported.... Thanks

Comment: Well maybe because we say so, or the fact its not supported. The value is used as-is (it is using Java String split that takes the value as an java regular expression). Or if you do not believe us then check the source code.